Bidual's Dude Banach
I have a question. It is always true that if $E$ is an e.v.n, then $E''$ (Bidual) is Banach?. I've been looking at a proof that if $x_k$ converges weakly to 0 and is also Cauchy, then it converges strongly to 0. And it uses the isometry of canonical injection and that $E''$ is Banach to prove that it converges.
The answer in Spanish:


What is an e.v.n.? A normed vector space? Then the answer is "yes". And what do you mean by "Dude" in the title of the question?

@PhoemueX Yes, I'm Sorry. But, why?

I understand that E' is Banach if E is, just as E'' is Banach if E' is. But if E is not Banach, how can E' be Banach and in turn E''?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026961/proof-of-dual-normed-vector-space-is-complete

Dude= doubt (span.)?
By Mathematica
  TextRecognize[pic, Language->{"Equation","Spanish"}]

we get (poor math discarded)

Por definición de sucesión de Cauchy, tenemos que 3mo € N de tal 
forma que: Luego, podemos utilizar el bi-dual con la inyección 
canónica tal que Como el bi-dual es un Banach, se tiene que para la 
norma bi-dual, la sucesión es convergente a un T para algún ma, Por 
lo cual, se tiene la convergencia puntual (de igual forma, se podía 
probar que como el doble-dual es Banach, la sucesión de Cauchy de 
inyecciones canónicas definidas anteriormente, en particular es 
convergente a un 7). Por otro lado, note que, por def de convergencia 
débil, Esto, pues  por lo cual   por ser lineales). Por unicidad del 
límite, se  tiene que Jy = T, por lo que, para m2 = máx(mg,m ), se 
tiene que: Concluyendo que la sucesión (2m) men converge fuertemente a 0.

google translate yields then

By definition of Cauchy sequence, we have that 3mo € N of such 
form that: Then, we can use the bi-dual with the injection 
canonical such that Since the bi-dual is a Banach, we have that for the 
bi-dual norm, the sequence is convergent to a T for some ma, For 
which, we have punctual convergence (in the same way, we could 
prove that since the double-dual is Banach, the Cauchy sequence of 
canonical injections defined above, in particular it is 
convergent to a 7). On the other hand, note that, by default of convergence 
weak, This, therefore because of being linear). By uniqueness of the 
limit, we have that Jy = T, so, for m2 = max(mg,m ), we 
has to: Concluding that the sequence (2m) men converges strongly to 0.

Unfortunately I have not yet finished my professional
  TextRecognize[x_, Language->{"Equation"->"LaTeX"}] 

module.
